# (Springboot) org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: json, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint

Hello
I'm trying to record an entity with sub entities using JSON, but it keeps giving me an error.
I can write the data separately, but when I cascade (nested) it fails. Any solution?

aqui estão as entidades

```
@Entity(name = "question")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Question extends PersistableObject{
    @Id
    Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();

    Date created = new Date();

    private String description;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Module module;
    //getters and setters
    // constructors
}

@Entity(name = "answer")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class Answer extends PersistableObject {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    Question nextQuestion;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_question")
    Question prevQuestion;


    private Date created = new Date();

    @Basic
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "module", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Module module;

}


@Entity(name = "module")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class Module extends PersistableObject {

    String description;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "module",cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "module",cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();

}

@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public abstract class PersistableObject extends RepresentationModel<PersistableObject> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    Date created = new Date();

}

@PostMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<Module> create(@RequestBody Module module) {

    Module result = moduleService.save(module);

    URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
            .path("/{id}")
            .buildAndExpand(result.getId())
            .toUri();

    return ResponseEntity
                .created(uri)
                .body(result);
}
```

And The JSON is

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "created": "2022-11-23T08:24:30.878+00:00",
    "description": "MDD",
    "answers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created": "2022-11-23T08:24:30.878+00:00",
            "description": "AN1",
            "moduleId": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "created": "2022-11-23T08:24:30.878+00:00",
            "description": "AN2",
            "moduleId": 1
        }
    ],
    "questions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created": "2022-11-23T08:24:30.878+00:00",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "created": "2022-11-23T08:24:30.878+00:00",
                    "description": "AN1",
                    "moduleId": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "created": "2022-11-23T08:24:30.878+00:00",
                    "description": "AN2",
                    "moduleId": 1
                }
            ],
            "description": "Q1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It looks like `moduleId` is unknown in `Answer` class. So, It looks like JPA tries to insert a `null` in the `module` column of Answer. Should it be `module: { id: 1 }` ?

Comment: @jhilton it was a mistake, but it's ignored because the attribute doesn't match.

Comment: and sorry for my english.